# How to read json response jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I am getting this string as `json` response from my handler. And now i want to display only the **Name** value in alert, just to test the functionality.... How can i do this?

String is in below:

```
{
    "files": [
        {
            "Thumbnail_url": null,
            "Name": "Chrysanthemum.jpg",
            "Length": 879394,
            "Type": "image/jpeg"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your JSON response is stored in `resp`.

```
alert(JSON.parse(resp).files[0].Name);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GdsQR/)**

```
jonObj.files[0].Name
```

If you have in string then you need to use `$.parseJSON` to convert it to json object.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wqnyx/1/)**

```
var jonObj = $.parseJSON('{"files": [{"Thumbnail_url": null, "Name": "Chrysanthemum.jpg", "Length": 879394,"Type": "image/jpeg"}]}');
alert(jonObj.files[0].Name);​
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to parse the JSON:

```
var result = JSON.parse('{"files":[{"Thumbnail_url":null,"Name":"Chrysanthemum.jpg","Length":879394,"Type":"image/jpeg"}]}')
```

Then you can refrence it using:

```
result.files[0].Name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Note the jQuery.parseJSON function
var response = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON_Response);
$.each(response, function(object) {
    $.each(response[object], function(values) {
        console.log(response[object][values].Name)
        console.log(response[object][values].Length)
    });
})​
```

Answer (score 0):

for that you can use [`jQuery.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) it does  Takes a well-formed JSON string and returns the resulting JavaScript object.

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"files":[{"Thumbnail_url":null,"Name":"Chrysanthemum.jpg","Length":879394,"Type":"image/jpeg"}]}');
```

and than

```
 obj.files[0].Name
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery then in the success function pass the data as param and access it in the `.each()` loop.

This should be this way:

```
$.each(data.files, function(i, el) {
  alert(el.name);
});
```